# Initialize and warmstart parameters on Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

If we initialize a variable `model.x` at a specific value (i.e. `model.x = 1`) before solving the model, do we need to have `warmstart=True` as parameter for the call of Pyomo's `solve()` method in order to keep those initial values for the optimization?

Keep in mind that an initialized variable should not be forced to take the specified value, it only provides the variable with an initial starting value and then the solver will change it if needed.

Comment: It depends on the solver interface that you are using within Pyomo.

Comment: Let's consider I might want to use them all. I used CPLEX, GUROBI, CBC and GLPK...

Comment: I've created a Github issue to this effect here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/387
I'm not familiar enough with the solver interfaces yet to know the answer straight off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it depends on the solver interface.

If you are using a solver through the NL-file interface (e.g., AMPL solvers), then initial variable values are always supplied to the solver (if they are not `None`), and it is up to the solver whether or not it attempts to use those values as a warmstart (e.g., for a MIP) or an initial iterate (e.g., for solvers that are using an optimization method that requires a starting point). For solvers that require a starting point, it is also up to the solver what value will be used for any variables that are not supplied a starting point. Often times zero is used, but this may vary between solvers.

For all other Pyomo solver interfaces (e.g., LP, MPS, Python), which mainly correspond to MIP solvers, I believe the default behavior is to **not** supply a warmstart. You have to specify `warmstart=True` when you call solve to have initial values communicated to the solver.

I do not find this consistent, mainly because when going through the the NL-file interface, the solve method does not even accept the `warmstart` keyword, so you have to have an if-statement when writing some general code that works with multiple interfaces.

I think I'll save further discussion for the GitHub issue.